# Azure synapse pipeline event trigger is failing to publish

Tags: azure, events, triggers, pipeline, azure-synapse

I have created an event trigger on a Synapse pipeline. When I publish the pipeline, I get an error:
`Forbidden. Role based access check failed for resource /subscriptions/..../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/...`

Has anyone managed to trigger a pipeline in Synapse using an event please? I have no problem doing this in Azure Data Factory.

Comment: Could you please re-try and do let us know if you are experiencing the same issue?

Comment: Could you please double check that you’re the owner of the storage account?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me, refer to access on storage account and Synapse in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-set-up-access-control#step-5-configure-admin-access-for-sql-pools). Below is GIF showing it

[image]